# Designing 4th order Butterworth Multiple feedback bandpass filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, active-filter, band-pass

I'm trying to design a 4th order Butterworth bandpass filter using Multiple feedback topology. The design requirements I am trying to achieve for this filter are; 
**Q factor = 10, Av = 11, fc = 100kHz , BW = 10kHz.**

In the book [Op-amps for every one book pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiR7-Ca9NbeAhVIzaQKHQ_MDcMQFjAAegQIDxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2F6.101%2Fwww%2Freference%2Fop_amps_everyone.pdf&usg=AOvVaw08CeWn2AHEo6ZLvui62EAA), I came across two design tables:

The **First** of the table correspond to my desired filter requirements with Q factor of 10 and filter coefficients values for the parameters `a1`, `b1`, `α`. And filter calculations are given as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The **Second** table shows different 4th order coefficients values for **ai,bi,Qi** and uses **ki**.

[image]

[image]

**My questions are;**

**1)** Why the two tables for 4th order Butterworth filter have different coefficients and `Q` factor values?

**2)** The coefficient parameters `a1`, `b1`, `Q`, `α` are the same as `ai`, `bi`, `Qi`, `ki` respectively?

**3)** Which is the appropriate table to use? If the second table is better for designing the filter. What are the calculations steps needed in using those coefficient parameters. Since no formulas are given in the book.

Comment: I think you see two lines for 4th order because it is implemented as two 2nd order sections. What you are seeing are the damping coefficients; one for each 2nd order section. 0.765 and 1.848 would be about the right values, too.

Comment: What @jonk said, plus you should take some time to read the rest of the book, it will be worth it. Who knows? Maybe you'll find other explanations in there, too.

Comment: LAD_145, may I direct your attention to the fact that table 16.5 contains LOWPASS parameters!!

Comment: It may motivate you to grab up more about this if I tell you that the two 2nd order damping values in that 16-5 table come from \$\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2}\:}\$, which themselves derive from \$2\operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{\pi}{2N}\left[2i-1\right]\right)\$, with \$i=1\$ and \$i=2\$.

Comment: LAD-145....I have a question: Are you required to use two second-order bandpass stages in series (staggerd tuning)? Are you aware that there are alternative (and better !) methods for designing a 4th-order bandpass?

Comment: @LvW for my design I am not restricted to use the staggered tuning. My only concern that it is 4th order.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a 2nd-order lowpass in series with a 2nd-order highpass (remember: A 4th-order bandpass has slopes of 2nd-order).

Comment: When using >2nd order Butterworth all breakpoints and Q’s are staggered to align the -3dB point and spread out eack pole on the semi-circular poles of this filter. but as I answered Av=11 * 100 kHz is not the GBW required, it must be multiplied by the max Q^2 as a minimum or 100 x. You are describing more like a 3dB ripple Chebychev

Comment: What sort of response accuracy do you expect from that thing anyway? Using typical 5 or 10% capacitors and 1% resistors, it's a wild guess what the response will actually be. Butterworth is a fantasy at that point. Op-amps also need to be excellent for this to work. If this is for a product, do you intend to tune each device individually? You may have way more success using switched-capacitor filters instead, since it'll take very few external components to do this, and the response will be rock-solid vs. time, temperature, and process spread.

Comment: TL;DR: Most theoretical high-order active filter designs are either unmanfacturable or expensive in both parts (including op-amps!) and tuning. They won't tell you that in many a book, because many of those books are written without anyone actually assembling the damn things and seeing how they work. You need a way to extract a Bode plot from the assembled prototype to see for yourself. Getting the performance to within 0.5dB of what you're after will be relatively tough and expensive. Digital filtering will be infinitely cheaper, usually.

Answer (score 1):

This design is going to deviate from expected performance due to insufficient GBW requirements.

With a gain of 3.3 in each stage with a Q of ~14 in each stage at staggered frequencies to achieve a net BW of 10% fc= 10kHz,  if one truly expects a Butterworth response 1 octave up, means the minimum GBW product is >> 50 MHz.   A GBW of 10MHz reduces the output 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Just above Table 16-2:

> ...with `a1`and `b1` being the second-order low-pass coefficients of the desired filter type.
>   To simplify the filter design, Table 16
>   –
>   2 lists those coefficients, and provides the 
>   `α`
>    values

The fourth order band-pass filter in that example is built from **two** partial second order filters. This method is called **staggered tuning**.

This means that the coefficients `a1` and `b1` of Table 16-2 are second order coefficients, and not fourth order coefficients.

Table 16-5. shows low-pass coefficients. Compare with Table 16-1:

[image]

Thus, you can use the *Table 16-2* and staggered tuning to design your fourth order band-pass filter.